# Binding Foreground Services with Activity

Tags: java, android, service

I am making a music player using `exoplayer` library. I am trying to use `foreground services` to run music in background. Here is my activity that handles music playback.

```
public class PlaybackActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

SimpleExoPlayer player;
String url;
private int lengthOfArray;
private int currentIndex;
private ImageButton play;
private ImageButton prev;
private ImageButton next;
private ArrayList<Songs> arrayList;
boolean playWhenReady;
long playbackPosition;
int currentWindow;
SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
ForegroundServices foregroundServices = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playback);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ForegroundServices.class);
    intent.setAction("START");
    startService(intent);

    Intent myIntent = getIntent();
    url = myIntent.getStringExtra("PATH");
    lengthOfArray = myIntent.getIntExtra("LENGTH", 0);
    currentIndex = myIntent.getIntExtra("INDEX", 0);
    arrayList = myIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("ARRAY");
    prev = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
    prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onPrev();
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }
    });
    play = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play_pause_button);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onPlayPause();
        }
    });
    next = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onNext();
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }
    });

    simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.audio_view);
    simpleExoPlayerView.setControllerHideOnTouch(false);
    simpleExoPlayerView.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(0);

}

private void initializePlayer(){
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this), new DefaultTrackSelector()
            , new DefaultLoadControl());

    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    player.seekTo(currentWindow,playbackPosition);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
    player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);


   // Intent startIntent = new Intent(PlaybackActivity.this, ForegroundServices.class);
   // startIntent.setAction("START");
   // startService(startIntent);


}


private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {

    DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "idk"), new DefaultBandwidthMeter());
    return new ExtractorMediaSource(uri,
            dataSourceFactory,
            new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
}




@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
        initializePlayer();
    }

    if (foregroundServices==null) {
        Intent intentBind = new Intent(this, ForegroundServices.class);
        bindService(intentBind, mConnection, 0);
    }
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        foregroundServices = ((ForegroundServices.MediaBinder)service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        foregroundServices = null;
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   // hideSystemUi();
    if ((Util.SDK_INT <= 23 || player == null)) {
        initializePlayer();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void hideSystemUi() {
    simpleExoPlayerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Util.SDK_INT <= 23) {
        releasePlayer();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (Util.SDK_INT > 23) {
        releasePlayer();
    }
}

private void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        playbackPosition = player.getCurrentPosition();
        currentWindow = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
        playWhenReady = player.getPlayWhenReady();
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}

public void pauseAndPlay(){
    player.setPlayWhenReady(!player.getPlayWhenReady());
}

public void onPlayPause(){
    if(player.getPlayWhenReady() == true){
        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }
    if(player.getPlayWhenReady() == false){
        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
    }

    pauseAndPlay();
}

public void onNext(){
    if (currentIndex == lengthOfArray - 1){
        currentIndex = 0;
        player.release();
        player.stop();
        Songs obj = arrayList.get(currentIndex);
        url = obj.getmData();
        initializePlayer();
    }
    else{
        currentIndex++;
        player.release();
        player.stop();
        Songs obj = arrayList.get(currentIndex);
        url = obj.getmData();
        initializePlayer();
    }
}

public void onPrev(){
    if(currentIndex == 0){
        Songs obj = arrayList.get(currentIndex);
        url = obj.getmData();
        player.release();
        player.stop();
        initializePlayer();
    }
    else{
        currentIndex--;
        Songs obj = arrayList.get(currentIndex);
        url = obj.getmData();
        player.release();
        player.stop();
        initializePlayer();
    }
}
```

}

and this my `ForegroundServices` class

```
public class ForegroundServices extends Service {


public ForegroundServices() {
}

class MediaBinder extends Binder
{
    ForegroundServices getService()
    {
        return ForegroundServices.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals("START")){
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PlaybackActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction("Main");
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundServices.class);
        previousIntent.setAction("Previous");
        PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                previousIntent, 0);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundServices.class);
        playIntent.setAction("PlayPause");
        PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                playIntent, 0);

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundServices.class);
        nextIntent.setAction("Next");
        PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                nextIntent, 0);

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.play);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Music Player")
                .setTicker("Music Player")
                .setContentText("My Music")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
                .setLargeIcon(
                        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous,
                        "Previous", ppreviousIntent)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Play",
                        pplayIntent)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next",
                        pnextIntent).build();

        startForeground(101, notification);

    }

    else if (intent.getAction().equals("Previous")) {
        PlaybackActivity pba = new PlaybackActivity();
        pba.onPrev();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("PlayPause")) {
        PlaybackActivity pba = new PlaybackActivity();
        pba.onPlayPause();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("Next")) {
        PlaybackActivity pba = new PlaybackActivity();
        pba.onNext();
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("Stop")) {
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

Now whenever i start `PlaybackActivity` from `MainActivity` the app crashes. I dont wanna use `initializeplayer` in `ForegroundServices`. Is there a way to make this services class and this activity to work together?

Comment: There's a [very detailed guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-an-audio-app.html) specifically around building an audio playback app, including both the service and activity side.

Comment: what do you need `class MediaBinder extends Binder` for if you dont use it anywhere (for example in `onBind` method)?

Comment: I am using it in `OnServiceConnected` .

Comment: do you know how to use `bound services" ? did you read official docs about it?

Comment: I have already seen that guide but still i cant figure out anything.

Comment: then read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), pay spacial attention on `"The basics"` section

Comment: @pskink actually no. i dont know how to use it. i have read the docs but cant understand anything.

Comment: Okay so can i solve my problem using bound services?

Comment: sure you can, whats unclear in "The basics" section? did you read it?

Comment: Yes i have read it. Sorry for my little knowledge but i am confused af rn.

Comment: okay i have done everything. I tried using bound services and tried to bind my service with my activity. I have also tried foreground services and writing some methods in it but nothing seems to work. Please help.

Comment: Could you please post your 'crash' stacktrace log?